# Calculating Daylight Savings Time without Libraries and System Calls

Tags: c#, c++, date, time

So, I am coding for a system with only a RTC containing monday, day, year, hour, minute, second and day of the week.

Without nice Libraries and System Calls, I am trying to create a way to simply calculate whether it is DST or not based on USA/Canada rules and Mexico rule.

Is this code the best way to do this for USA where the rule is "Second Sunday March 2AM to First Sunday November 2AM"

```
switch (TestDateTime->Month)
{
    case 1:
    case 2:
    case 12:
        // January, February and December are definitely NOT DST months
        u8RetVal = FALSE;
        break;

    case 4:
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
    case 10:
        // April, May, June, July, August, September, October are definitely FULL DST months
        u8RetVal = TRUE;
        break;

    case 3:
        // At this point, this is March is a partial DST month
        i8PreviousSunday = TestDateTime->DayOfMonth - TestDateTime->DayOfWeek;

        // In march, we are DST if our previous sunday was on or after the 8th.
        if (i8PreviousSunday >= 8)
        {
            // So if it is the 2nd week of March and the day is a Sunday, check the time for less than 2AM, if so, it isn't DST yet
            if ((TestDateTime->DayOfMonth >= 8) && (TestDateTime->DayOfMonth <= 14) && (TestDateTime->DayOfWeek == 0) && (TestDateTime->Hours < 2))
            {
                u8RetVal = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                u8RetVal = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            u8RetVal = FALSE;
        }
        break;

    case 11:
        // At this point, this is November is a partial DST month
        i8PreviousSunday = TestDateTime->DayOfMonth - TestDateTime->DayOfWeek;

        // In november we must be before the first sunday to be in DST.  That means the previous sunday must be before the 1st.
        if (i8PreviousSunday <= 0)
        {
            // This falls on the Monday-Saturday before the first Sunday, so we are still DST
            u8RetVal = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            // This falls on the first Sunday and later.  So, a catch for the Sunday of the first week, if not 2AM yet, we are still DST.
            if ((TestDateTime->DayOfMonth >= 1) && (TestDateTime->DayOfMonth <= 7) && (TestDateTime->DayOfWeek == 0) && (TestDateTime->Hours < 2))
            {
                u8RetVal = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                u8RetVal = FALSE;
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        // Invalid Month
        u8RetVal = FALSE;
        break;
}
```

And then for Mexico where the rule is First Sunday April 2AM to Last Sunday October 2AM.

```
switch (TestDateTime->Month)
{
    case 1:
    case 3:
    case 2
    case 11:
    case 12:
        // January, February, March, November and December are definitely NOT DST months
        u8RetVal = FALSE;
        break;

    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
    case 9:
        // May, June, July, August, September are definitely FULL DST months
        u8RetVal = TRUE;
        break;

    case 4:
        // At this point, this is April is a partial DST month
        i8PreviousSunday = TestDateTime->DayOfMonth - TestDateTime->DayOfWeek;

        // In march, we are DST if our previous sunday was on or after the 1st.
        if (i8PreviousSunday >= 1)
        {
            // So if it is the 2nd week of March and the day is a Sunday, check the time for less than 2AM, if so, it isn't DST yet
            if ((TestDateTime->DayOfMonth >= 1) && (TestDateTime->DayOfMonth <= 7) && (TestDateTime->DayOfWeek == 0) && (TestDateTime->Hours < 2))
            {
                u8RetVal = FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                u8RetVal = TRUE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            u8RetVal = FALSE;
        }
        break;

    case 10:
        // At this point, this is October is a partial DST month
        i8PreviousSunday = TestDateTime->DayOfMonth - TestDateTime->DayOfWeek;

        // In October we must be before the last Sunday, which will always be one of the last 7 days
        if (i8PreviousSunday <= 24)
        {
            // This falls on the Monday-Saturday before the first Sunday, so we are still DST
            u8RetVal = TRUE;
        }
        else
        {
            // This falls on the first Sunday and later.  So, a catch for the Sunday of the first week, if not 2AM yet, we are still DST.
            if ((TestDateTime->DayOfMonth >= 25) && (TestDateTime->DayOfMonth <= 31) && (TestDateTime->DayOfWeek == 0) && (TestDateTime->Hours < 2))
            {
                u8RetVal = TRUE;
            }
            else
            {
                u8RetVal = FALSE;
            }
        }
        break;

    default:
        // Invalid Month
        u8RetVal = FALSE;
        break;
}
```

I am assuming either the code is good, which I think it might be.  Or it can help someone else later by the discussion if it is or isn't.

Comment: Don't the details of DST change every year according to some big wigs' whims? AFAIK this is one of the many date/time problems that's nigh impossible to solve with an algorithm and has to be pulled from a data base.

Comment: @delnan not every near, not even close. The rules do change occasionally, though, so know that your code (if you hardcode it like this) might need to change eventually.

Comment: Well, yes, that is why making it part of an upgradable application is far better than depending on libraries from some 3rd party compiler maker.  This is why I am asking this, if the above looks right to people other than me, then perhaps the thought behind can be used by other embedded developers as well.  I am ok with having to change later as that is what government approvals for this software entails anyway.

Comment: The state of Arizona has some exceptions: https://www.google.com/#q=arizona+daylight+savings

Comment: Why are you using an unsigned 8-bit return value when you could use a type `bool`?  You could use the standard Boolean values: `true` and `false`.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews - You are assuming I am using a .NET compiler or a compiler with bool type.  This is for an embedded system, not using .NET and using a custom 3rd party compiler, so I have limited types as compared with more modern compilers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - Thank you, I am aware that Arizona has exceptions as well as Mexican disctricts, PR, Guam, American Somoa, Marianna Islands, Virgin Islands as well as parts of Quebec, Saskatchewan, British Colombia do not use it as well.  This does not concern the question at hand.  The question is, does the above code detect daylight's savings time properly.  Whether you, as a user, enable or not is not the problem of the code.

Comment: @RallyRabbit: You tagged your question with C++, and C++ has a `bool` type even for embedded systems.  This is one area where C and C++ languages differ.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews - Yes I did.  And I am telling you, this compiler does not have a bool type.  Every type is a minimum 8-bits and rests of 8 bit boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses C#'s `DateTime` class, but should work with your code too:

```
public static DateTime GetDay(int year, int month, int ordinal,
                              DayOfWeek dayOfWeek, bool fromStart)
{
    DateTime result = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
    if (!fromStart)
        result = result.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);
    int mult = fromStart ? 1 : -1;
    for (; result.DayOfWeek != dayOfWeek; result = result.AddDays(1 * mult));
    for (int i = 1; i < ordinal; result = result.AddDays(7 * mult), i++);
    return result;
}

// use like this
// meaning: in 2013, in March, find the second Sunday, from the beginning
GetDay(2013, 3, 2, DayOfWeek.Sunday, true); // US start, Mar 10
GetDay(2013, 11, 1, DayOfWeek.Sunday, true); // US end, Nov 3
GetDay(2013, 4, 1, DayOfWeek.Sunday, true); // MX start, Apr 7
// meaning: in 2013, in October, find the first Sunday, from the end
GetDay(2013, 10, 1, DayOfWeek.Sunday, false); // MX end, Oct 27
```

Then some simple date comparison will tell you whether a target time is DST or not, except for the hours right around DST. That gets more complicated, and you really need to store more info than you say you are, e.g. store a UTC timestamp and then convert it when needed, e.g. to differentiate 1:30 AM CST and 1:30 AM CDT on a "fall back" day.

(I know that your code is C++, but as you also tagged this C#, I presumed that a C# solution would be acceptable - it shouldn't be hard to translate this method to your context)